# Travis is not finding my .travis.yml file since a repo name change

Tags: travis-ci

How can I delete the repo and reset it as a new one or how long does it take to smarten up normally?

Answer (score 1):

Hit the **sync** button at the top of your travis profile page. Travis will refetch all your Github repos where you can reactivate the repository with the changed name.